# I would like to select the value and return on the same page from database using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, node.js

This is the node API coding for post method which will return the data from mysql database

```
 // these my post method
 app.post('/home/product',function (req,res) {
   var data = {
      name:req.body.name
   };
   con.getConnection(function(err,connect) {
      if (err) throw err;
      connect.query("SELECT price,quantity from product WHERE name = ?",data.name,function 
      (err, result, fields) {
         if (err) throw err;
         res.send(result);
         connect.release();
      });
   });
 //con.end();
});
```

I want to read value from html input box and call a AJAX function

```
// this is the html-element
<input class="fname" id="product" name="product" placeholder="Product 
      name"style="width:80%"/>
<button id="btncheckproduct">check</button>
<input type="text" name="priceperunit" id="priceperunit">
<input type="text" name="availableproduct" id="availableproduct">
```

There is AJAX script which will take input and return value in the other textbox

```
// Ajax Script
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('#btncheckproduct').click(()=>{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
         name:$("#product").val()
        },
      url: '/home/product',
      dataType: FormData,
      success:(data) => {
          //console.log(data);
          $('#priceperunit').val(data[0].price);
          $('#availableproduct').val(data[0].quantity);
        }
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

All I want to get value return on the basis of given name in text field, But I am not getting actual value

when I go for running it. It is not calling the POST method and not giving return back, but as I change method to GET it return value but not in case of POST

Comment: Can you add more details on what error you are getting , In your html you also need to add two inputs/div elements with id's 'priceperunit' and 'availableproduct' in order for the result to display the price and quantity of the products from database.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?  You've said you'd "like to do A" then shown how you've done A; but there's no description of what's not working or what else you're trying to do.

Comment: when I go for running it. It is not calling the POST method and not giving return back, but as I change method to GET it return value but not in case of POST